# Tile map collision in SFML game C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm creating a game in C++ using SFML library, and during implementation tile map collision(i'm loading map from txt file - 1's stand for platforms, 0's for free space). https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnEcV.jpg

I came across a problem with handling all four type of collisions at the same time(from bottom, top, left and right).What I mean: when there is no collision, the player can normally move, but if we hit the wall, collision appears only for FIRST written if() statement(in our example only right collision occurs, rest are being omitted). Here's my code (i'll paste only necessary things)

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    Player(sf::Texture* texture, sf::Vector2u imageCount, sf::Vector2f position, float switchTime, float speed, float jumpSpeed);
    ~Player();

    void UpdatePlayer(float deltaTime);

    float top, right, left, bottom;

private:
    sf::Vector2f _position;
    float groundHeight = 40; //i've added gravity and hardcoded the ground height to create jumping 
    float _jumpSpeed; // later on, it will be replaced with bottom collision
    const float gravity = 981.0f;
    sf::RectangleShape body;
    float _speed;

};

//Player.cpp
void Player::UpdatePlayer(float deltaTime)
{
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.0f, 0.0f);

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        movement.x -= _speed * deltaTime; //we are using delta time in order to move the object in according to time
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        movement.x += _speed * deltaTime;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        movement.y = -sqrt(5.0f * gravity * _jumpSpeed) * deltaTime;
    }
    if (body.getPosition().y + body.getSize().y < groundHeight || movement.y < 0)
    {
        movement.y += gravity * deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        body.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, groundHeight - body.getSize().y);
        movement.y = 0;
    }



    bottom = body.getPosition().y + body.getSize().y;
    left = body.getPosition().x;
    right = body.getPosition().x + body.getSize().x;
    top = body.getPosition().y;


    body.move(movement);
```

}

//Source.cpp

```
 void LoadCollisionMap(const char*filename)
{
    std::ifstream openfile(filename);
    std::vector<int> tempMap;
    CollMap.clear();

    if (openfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!openfile.eof())
        {
            std::string str, value;
            std::getline(openfile, str);
            std::stringstream stream(str);

            while (std::getline(stream, value, ' '))
            {
                if (value.length() > 0)
                {
                    int a = atoi(value.c_str());
                    tempMap.push_back(a);
                }
            }
            CollMap.push_back(tempMap);
            tempMap.clear();
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    LoadCollisionMap("Map2.txt"); //Collision map

Player player(&playerTexture, sf::Vector2u(3, 9),sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 150.0f) ,0.3f, 400.0f, 555.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < CollMap.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < CollMap[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (CollMap[i][j] == 1)
            {

                int CollBottom, CollRight, CollLeft, CollTop;
                CollBottom = i * 32 + 32;
                CollTop = i * 32;
                CollLeft = j * 32;
                CollRight = j * 32 + 32;

                if (player.right < CollLeft || player.left > CollRight || player.top > CollBottom || player.bottom < CollTop)
                {
                    //no collision
                }
                else
                {


                    if (player.right > CollLeft)
                    {
                        std::cout << "collision" << std::endl;
                        player.body.setPosition(player.body.getPosition().x - 1, player.body.getPosition().y);
                        break;

                    }


                    if (player.left < CollRight)
                    {
                        std::cout << "collision 2" << std::endl;
                        player.body.setPosition(player.body.getPosition().x + 1, player.body.getPosition().y);
                        break;
                    }


                    if (player.top < CollBottom)
                    {
                        std::cout << "collision 3" << std::endl;

                        player.body.setPosition(player.body.getPosition().x, player.body.getPosition().y + 1);


                        break;


                    }

                    if (player.bottom > CollTop)
                    {
                        std::cout << "collision 4" << std::endl;

                        player.body.setPosition(player.body.getPosition().x, player.body.getPosition().y - 1);
                        break;
                    }


                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator `break` return you immediately from the most nested loop. If you want to check all collisions, you should remove `break` from collision checking, and replace it for example with bool variable.

```
bool collisionDetected = false;

if (player.right > CollLeft)
{
    std::cout << "collision" << std::endl;
    player.body.setPosition(player.body.getPosition().x - 1, player.body.getPosition().y);

    collisionDetected = true;
}

...

if( collisionDetected ) 
    break;
```

Comment: I've made like you suggested, but now when i m hitting the wall, the player just go through it. What's more i realized that all four types of collisions are executed at the same time(no matter from which side i m colliding).

Comment: @Simon sorry, my fault that I removed setting player's body's position from collision processing. Example fixed. And yes, all collisions are checked during one loop iteration, but I think that shouldn't make trouble.

Comment: I've tried it with setting position also, but still with no succeed. I decided not to perform all types of collisions in 1 for loop but in 4 different ones(for example (CollMap[i][j] == 1, if (CollMap[i][j] == 2) and so on...) but i had to change my txt file and now it look like this. https://imgur.com/a/24UAK

Comment: 1's stand for collision on right, 2's for left, 3's for bottom and 4's are treated as a ceiling. And it works :)